# Why java ExecutorService execute takes in a new Runnable implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

In the given snippet below:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); //create a fixed thread pool

executor.execute(new Thread(() -> foo()));
executor.execute(new Thread(() -> foo()));
executor.execute(new Thread(() -> foo()));
```

In the above example how many threads are created 2 or 3?

- **2**: because the executor pool size is 2.
- **3**: as in the code I do new Thread 3 times.

Why not `executor.execute(Callable);` ?

Comment: [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) accepts `Runnable`, not `Thread` specifically. Although `Thread` is runnable, there's no reason to use it with `execute`. Why use `Thread` in the above?

Comment: *"In the above example how many threads are created 2 or 3?"* Do you mean OS threads? Or `Thread` instances?

Comment: You actually creating a new thread inside the scheduled task. Do not use thread pools with java.lang.Thread is have no sense.

Comment: I mean OS Thread. But when you say new Thread() in java it also implicitly means new OS thread right? So it becomes quite misleading.

Comment: java.lang.Thread behavior depends on jvm (vendor and version). Sun/Oracle HotSpot java uses fibers (also known as co-routines) before version 1.6, and starting from this version threads - are native OS threads. I.e. new Thread( ... ) really creating new OS native thread with HotSpot.

Comment: @VictorGubin, Re, "You actually creating a new thread inside the scheduled task" The only thing we can say about what happens _inside_ the tasks is that they call `foo()`. We don't know what `foo()` does.  The code snippet creates three new `Thread` instances _before_ submitting those to the executor, but we can't really call them "threads" because they are never `start()`ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally: Don't use `Thread` with [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)), use `Runnable`. As you noted, it's the job of the `ExecutorService` to handle threads.

> In the above example how many threads are created 2 or 3?

You've clarified in the comments that you mean OS threads there.

Either two or five (full-on threads or fibers). Almost certainly not three. Could be one or four. Nice precise answer. :-) Here's the reasoning:

There are definitely three `Thread` instances created, as you're doing that explicitly. That doesn't mean that three OS threads have been created as a result. The JavaDoc for `Thread` doesn't explicitly say that the OS thread is created when the `Thread` object is created or later when/if `start` is called, and it's likely down to the implementation. Since you never call `start`, we don't know that any OS threads are created for those `Thread` instances.

So in terms of OS threads, it could be:

- Just one or two, created and started by the `ExecutorService` in response to the fact you've called `execute` two or more times and the limit set when creating the service was two threads. Initially I assumed it would create two threads for sure given those three calls, but [Aleksandr Semyannikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5219732/aleksandr-semyannikov) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874326/why-java-executorservice-execute-takes-in-a-new-runnable-implementation/58874507#comment104016974_58874507) that the `ExecutorService` may not have to create both threads. The work being scheduled by those `execute` calls is just a single method call (though we have no idea how long that method takes to run). So it may be able to reuse just one thread. I tend to doubt it (I think the first thread will still be allocated to the first `execute` call when your second one is made), but my confidence level on that is no more than 60%. :-) If it were really important, I'd test it (though offhand I'm not quite sure *how* I'd test it).
- Four or five: three created by `new Thread` and one-two created and started by the `ExecutorService`.

My money's on two.

I think we can rule out three. To get the answer three, the `ExecutorService` implementation would have to use the threads you pass it, which it almost certainly won't.

---

On my Linux system, I can confirm that my version of Java starts out with 15 (!) threads and when the code above runs, two more are created. I can also confirm that those threads are pool threads, not the threads from `new Thread`. I used this off-the-cuff code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Example {
    private static void foo() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(20000);
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); //create a fixed thread pool

        executor.execute(new Thread(() -> foo()));
        executor.execute(new Thread(() -> foo()));
        executor.execute(new Thread(() -> foo()));
    }
}
```

and during the 20s wait used `ps aux | grep java` to get the PID of the process and `top -H -pPID` (where PID is the pid) to see the threads.

Comment: Thanks This was my misconceptions _"The JavaDoc for Thread doesn't explicitly say that the OS thread is created when the Thread object is created"_

Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Great answer. If I remember right `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)` will not create 2 threads immediately, and it literally means that after the last `execute` there could be from 4 to 5 threads.

Comment: @AleksandrSemyannikov - Good point, I was thinking the service would create both threads because there were two or more calls to `execute`, but it's *possible* that each of the calls to `foo` was completed so quickly that the same thread was available to be used for all three. I tend to doubt it, but I wouldn't trust my intuition on threading in Java if it were important, I'd test it. (Now I'm wondering...*how* would I test it? But that's a digression...)

Answer (score 0):

2.

Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int n) creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. **At any point, at most n Threads threads will be active** processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)